# UTL_SMTP service not available error

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, smtp, email-attachments

I am getting service not available message when I am sending mail with large size attachment.

The requirement is to write a procedure which will extract the data of the whole table and send the extract as excel attachment in mail. table_name and email id will be passed as a parameter.

I tried with the CLOB. fetched the data from the table and put it into a CLOB as an XML structure. Then I am sending the mail with attachment as xls with the data present in CLOB.

For a lesser number of records(max around 2k) is working fine. But when I am checking for more number of records, the program is throwing an error of UTL_SMTP transient error - Service not available.

## Following is the part of code where I am utilising UTL_SMTP.

```
BEGIN   
vsql   := 'SELECT * from test_table';

V_CLOB := get_query_output(vsql);

v_lob := v_clob;

  v_connection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection('abcd.efgh.com');

UTL_SMTP.helo(v_connection, 'abcd.efgh.com');

UTL_SMTP.mail(v_connection, p_from);   
UTL_SMTP.rcpt(v_connection, p_to);   
UTL_SMTP.open_data(v_connection);

UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);   

UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(V_CONNECTION, 'To: ' || P_TO || UTL_TCP.CRLF);

utl_smtp.write_data(v_connection, 'Cc: ' || p_cc || utl_tcp.crlf);

UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection,
                      'Subject: NPI Error Report' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('at position 4');  

 UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection,
                      'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' ||
                      c_mime_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection,
                      'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.' ||
                      UTL_TCP.crlf);



  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection,
                      '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(V_CONNECTION,
                      'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.CRLF); 



   -- Set up attachment header 

UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection,
                      'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' ||
                      'Error_Report.xls' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);

   UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf);


  -- start attachment


  V_LEN := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(V_CLOB);


     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_LEN :=' || V_LEN);


  for I in 0 .. TRUNC((V_LEN - 1) / V_INDEX) LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(v_connection,
                        DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(V_LOB, V_INDEX, I * V_INDEX + 1)); 

  END LOOP;

     --   -- End attachment   UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_connection, UTL_TCP.crlf); 

  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(V_CONNECTION,
                      '--' || C_MIME_BOUNDARY || '--' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);


     UTL_SMTP.close_data(v_connection);   UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);  

 EXCEPTION   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    BEGIN

      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(v_connection);

        raise;
    END;
     END;
```

Error Codes which I am getting when there are huge records(almost >2k) in the table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uezav.png)

```
Error report -
ORA-29277: invalid SMTP operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 82
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 212
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 622
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 633
ORA-06512: at line 328
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
29277. 00000 -  "invalid SMTP operation"
*Cause:    The SMTP operation was invalid at the current stage of the SMTP
           transaction.
*Action:   Retry the SMTP operation at the appropriate stage of the SMTP
           transaction.
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: This seems like a discussion you should be having with the admin looking after the email server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit .. Part of the code I added to the description. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. Put error message as text.

Answer (score 0):

The error is strange, usually this is not related to size of attached file. 
Maybe your attachment causes problems with special characters, try to send the mail like this:

```
ClobLen PLS_INTEGER;
amount BINARY_INTEGER := 8192;
buffer VARCHAR2(16384);
offset PLS_INTEGER := 1;

BEGIN 

    ....

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, '--'||C_MIME_BOUNDARY || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Type: text/plain; name="Error_Report.xls"'|| Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Error_Report.xls"'|| Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);

    offset := 1;
    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(V_LOB);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN offset > ClobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(V_LOB, amount, offset, BUFFER);
        UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data(con, Utl_Raw.cast_to_raw(BUFFER));
        offset := offset + amount;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(con, '--'||C_MIME_BOUNDARY||'--' || Utl_Tcp.CRLF);
```

Perhaps the error is not caused by main block but by exception handler. Change your exception handler from

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
BEGIN
   UTL_SMTP.QUIT(v_connection);
   raise;
END;
END;
```

to

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
        UTL_SMTP.quit(v_connection);
        RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I tried this approach and got the same issue again.

Comment: Thanks! Even if I don't place exception block, still I am getting the same error message. I changed the exception block as suggested. But still I am facing the same issue. Please note, the code is working fine when the table contains less number of records. if the record count is high (say > around 2000 records) then only I am getting this error message. Is there anything related to SMTP file size restriction?